# Are there XML namespaces whose mere mentioning has side-effects? E.g. in SOAP 1.1?

Tags: xml, soap, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

Can the inclusion (declaration) of a namespace like "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" in an XML document have side-effects or change its interpretation, even if the declared namespace prefix is not used anywhere?

I see a lot of examples on the 'net - including various official specifications - and also in data transmitted by clients, where certain seemingly superfluous namespace declarations abound, as though to ward off evil. Their occurrence in actual transmitted data could be ascribed to careless/sloppy coding, but that's not the case for examples in published specifications.

A somewhat synthetic example, reduced to the bare essentials:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      xmlns:enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Body>
      <example xmlns="acme-URI">
         <foo xmlns="">meow<foo>
      </example>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

In case it matters, I'm mostly concerned with SOAP 1.1 messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the application that is processing the XML. It's not common or recommended practice, but it is theoretically possible for an receiving application to do something different if a particular namespace is declared, even though it is unused.

More commonly such namespaces are just present through carelessness on the part of the programmer generating the XML, or because XML editors include certain namespaces by default when you open a new document.

I have only ever come across one XML vocabulary that requires namespaces to be declared on an element even if they are not used on element or attribute names: see section 5.1.1 of http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much. My intention here was to achieve greater insight into the standards, so that I can distinguish odd-but-standard requirements from the peculiar requirements of specific applications or frameworks (which will be handled in a different fashion, which is necessary anyway for dealing with the invalid XML produced by some of our clients' software). Thanks also for pointing out an instance where a standard is itself decidedly peculiar...